# Why is it recommended to manually provision pre-existing secrets in AWS SecretsManager as opposed via CDK/Cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Quote from the [aws cdk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager-readme.html):

> If you need to use a pre-existing secret, the recommended way is to manually provision the secret in AWS SecretsManager and use the Secret.fromSecretArn or Secret.fromSecretAttributes method to make it available in your CDK Application

Why is that? Is it because it's not ideal to save the plain text secret into code?

Or we don't want the secret to appear in the cloudformation template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes.  Earlier CDK versions did not even permit passing text values to the `Secret` constructor.  We [only recently got](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/commit/dd90b8e9b3fe46ccc18a2472623ff27ef7989fbb) the [secretStringBeta1: string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretstringbeta1) prop along with a stern warning:

> It is **highly** encouraged to leave this field undefined and allow SecretsManager to create the secret value. The secret string -- if provided -- will be included in the output of the cdk as part of synthesis, and will appear in the CloudFormation template in the console. This can be secure(-ish) if that value is merely reference to another resource (or one of its attributes), but if the value is a plaintext string, it will be visible to anyone with access to the CloudFormation template (via the AWS Console, SDKs, or CLI).

Our CDK code and generated templates are meant to be [deterministic and version-controlled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps), further heightening the risk of leakage if plaintext secrets are used.

**Edit:**  Per @gshpychka's comment, a safe alternative to importing with `Secret.fromSecretArn` is to construct a new `Secret` without a secret value.  This creates a secret with a random password, which you change post-deploy in the Console.  This approach helpfully ties the secret's lifecycle to the Stack and lets you set its properties in the context of the Stack.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it can be a good idea to create the secrets in CDK, and then manually populate them in the console. This way, you can modify the secret's properties, like the resource policy and tags.

Comment: @gshpychka With that approach, won't Cloudformation detect it as some sort of drift? Since you changed it's state outside of CDK/CF?

Comment: @fedonev One worry I have with letting secrets manager generate the password via cdk is it being non-deterministic. When we tear down the stack and start it up again, it'll reset the values, thus losing the original secret values. Is that ok?

Comment: No, it will not detect any drift.

Comment: @froi Horses for courses.  Which option is "better" depends on use case specifics.